# sync two huge filesystems

Tags: linux, synchronization

I need to sync two huge file systems regularly in one direction. Both sides run linux with full root access.

My preferred solution: I can read the list of changed files and directories and sync only the changed files. But how can I get the list of changes? Inotify needs a handler for every directory, but there are too many. Maybe from the journal of the file system?

Here are some solutions and why they don't fit:

- rsync: Needs to check recursively all files. There are some million files and only little changes. The check takes too long.
- inotify: I need a handler for every directory and there too many. Inotify was not build for "watch all files" scenarios.
- DRDB: Both sides should run independent. It can happen that the hosts can't connect for some days.

Both machines need to synced about every 15 minutes. The initial sync is no problem, this question is only about syncing the changes.

Comment: Sync them once, regularly, or continuously?

Comment: Do you know previously the list of changed files? In other words, do you keep track of all changed files somehow? Otherwise, you need to compare the whole directory tree to know what has changed since last sync.

Comment: How far out of sync can the filesystems be, i.e. do they need to be within 1 minute, 10 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day of each other?

Comment: I updated the question: I only care about syncing the changes about every 15 minutes. Initial sync is not problem.

Comment: You say "rsync... takes too long" - how long does it take, and how long would be acceptable? You say DRBD is unacceptable since both sides should be independent - could you expand on why this is? It _seems_ like this question is moving away from "sync two filesystems" and towards "how do I quickly find all changes that happened within the last some-period-of-time"

Comment: Also: are there going to be changes on both filesystems, or is this more of a master-slave relationship?

Comment: @nickgrim unfortunately I don't have any exact numbers. But it takes some minutes for rsync to build the files list. Old rsync versions failed because it kept all filenames in memory (new versions can handle it). But it has an other drawback: it creates useless IO on the server and the linux buffers get filled with unneeded stuff (unchanged directory and file names).

Answer (score 4):

How about GlusterFS? I have found that the traffic it develops is considerable less than DRBD.

Comment: Sadly enough, websites go stale, even personal ones. As such, it may be a VERY good idea to summarise the key points of the how to so people in future could work out what is going on, especially if the link goes down.

Comment: while I do agree with @JourneymanGeek, I still would say +1 to Gluster

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This ensures that the answer will remain available even if the link goes dead. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: And there it happened. New URL is apparently http://www.chriscowley.me.uk/blog/2012/02/08/home-made-redundant-thin-provisioned-san/

Answer (score 0):

+1 for GlusterFS, it's a userspace Storage Clustering platform, it's pretty easy to setup, and works at file level.

Once installed all you need to do is create a new replicated Gluster Volume on the main server, it will replicate the contents realtime over TCP/IP. Then setup the client (which is basically mounting a filesystem), you can even do that on one of the servers and then write data always to that new mounted filesystem.